# accessing headers during fetch API call renders file data unusable

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Changing the syntax within the first return of my fetch API call renders my zip file invalid. I have no idea why.
After looking at [Why does .json() return a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555031/why-does-json-return-a-promise) I modified my tentative code but to still no avail.

This works :

```js
fetch("/photos/download_photos", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
})
    .then(response => {
        return response.blob();
    })
    .then(response => {
        const blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/zip'});
        const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = downloadUrl;
        a.download = "blah.zip";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    });
```

This doesn't :

```js
fetch("/photos/download_photos", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
})
    .then(response => {
        response.blob().then((data) => {return {
            data: data,
            fileName: response.headers.get("content-disposition").split('; filename="')[1].slice(0, -1)}});
        };
    })
    .then((res) => {
        const blob = new Blob([res.data], {type: 'application/zip'});
        const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = downloadUrl;
        a.download = res.fileName;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    });
```

The only difference is I also access the `headers` property of the response to use it to name the file. Is there an interaction between `response.headers` and the `blob()` function that I am not aware of ?
`res` in the second `then` is `undefined` in the second version of the code.

Comment: You forgot to return the Promise inside the first `.then`

Comment: Thanks for replying. Not sure what you mean unfortunately. How should I modify my code so that it works ?

Comment: Add `return` so that the `.then` returns something. The syntax for returning an expression in JS is `return <someExpression>`